# Spring Batch connection to Oracle DataBase

Tags: spring

I am Using Spring Batch for Writing Data from flat file to Oracle DB .But i am getting error for Automatic Table Creation .Can Anyone Please Help On this.

org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" 
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

<bean id="report" class="com.mkyong.model.Report" scope="prototype" />

<batch:job id="reportJob">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="cvsFileItemReader" writer="oracleItemWriter"
                commit-interval="2">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="cvsFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">

    <!-- Read a csv file -->
    <property name="resource" value="classpath:cvs/report.csv" />

    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">

            <!-- split it -->
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="names" value="date,impressions,clicks,earning" />
                </bean>
            </property>

            <property name="fieldSetMapper">

                <!-- return back to reader, rather than a mapped object. -->
                <!--
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PassThroughFieldSetMapper" />
                -->

                <!-- map to an object -->
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                    <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="report" />
                </bean>

            </property>

        </bean>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="oracleItemWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql">
        <value>
        <![CDATA[        
            insert into RAW_REPORT(DATE1,IMPRESSIONS,CLICKS,EARNING) values (:date, :impressions, :clicks, :earning)
        ]]>
        </value>
    </property>
    <!-- It will take care matching between object property and sql name parameter -->
    <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

DataBase.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd">

<!-- connect to database -->
<!-- <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Sakila" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean> -->

<!-- <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
</bean>
```

-->
   
        
    </bean> -->

```
<!-- <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
     <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
     <property name="databaseType" value="oracle" />
     <property name="tablePrefix" value="BATCH_"/>
     <property name="isolationLevelForCreate" value="ISOLATION_DEFAULT"/>
</bean>   -->

<bean id="jobRepository"
class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
<property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
    <property name="username" value="system"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

 <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />  

<!-- create job-meta tables automatically -->
<!-- <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql" />
    <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql" />
</jdbc:initialize-database> -->


<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource"  >
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-oracle10g.sql" />
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-oracle10g.sql" />
     <!-- <jdbc:script location="classpath:oracle10g/initial-query.sql" /> -->

</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

Context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

<!-- stored job-meta in database -->
<bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="databaseType" value="oracle" />
</bean>

<!-- stored job-meta in memory -->
<!-- 
<bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>
-->

<bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>
```

Thanks
Sh anti Bhushan

Answer (score 0):

The sequence in which script should be run is , Drop schema/tables first and then create the schema/tables.

i.e.

```
<jdbc:script location="classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-oracle10g.sql" />

<jdbc:script location="classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-oracle10g.sql" />
```

you are using opposite sequence , which means dropping tables - hence, you get table or view doesnot exists.(because the tables/schemas are dropped)

Answer (score 0):

I see the bad SQL grammar - Looks like the meta data table haven't been created in order to have results to return for the select queries. Check if the meta data table have been created and existing in db.